# Change mass UITableView background dynamically, but how?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, dynamic, background

I have a lot of `UITableViewControllers`, and I want to have custom background color, and I don't want to copy this to all TVC:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundPattern.png"]];
```

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can subclass UITableViewController with your own class, change the backgroundcolor in this class and derive the UITableViewControllers from this one.

Comment: I tried, but nothing changes. I put the code into the init method "// Custom initialization" and tried in the viewdidload, i also googled a couple of times, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `UIAppearance` protocol. You can specify the background color of table views globally or when contained in specific view controller classes:

```
UITableView *appearance = [UITableView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyTableViewController Class], [MyOtherTableViewController class], nil];
appearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundPattern.png"]];
```

You can put this in your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Also, the `view` and `tableView` properties of `UITableViewController` point to the same thing, so you don't need to set both.

**EDIT**

Try watching the 2012 WWDC video titled [Customizing the Appearance of UIKit Controls](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/). They demonstrate the `UIAppearance` protocol as well as a theme design pattern you may find useful.

Comment: I have more than ten TableViewController and a few UIViewControllers with Tableviews inside. And there will be even more of then, i don't think this is the best and most dynamic way to solve this.

Comment: The problem you're describing is exactly what the appearance protocol is intended for, so I don't get your objection. For example, if all your tables have the same background color, it takes one line of code. And it isn't static, so I don't get "dynamic" comment. Take a look at the `UIAppearance` protocol doc and maybe it will become more clear.

Comment: Added a WWDC video link in my answer. Take a look.

Comment: After adding this custom appearance, my `MFMailComposeViewController` started to crash my app all the time it presented, so be careful using this method!